TypeScript Error: defineRouting expects 0 arguments but got 1 during npm run build
I'm encountering a TypeScript error when running npm run build in my Next.js project that uses next-intl. Interestingly, the error does not occur when I run npm run dev; everything works as expected in the development environment.

./i18n/routing.ts:4:38
Type error: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

  2 | import { defineRouting } from "next-intl/routing";
  3 |
  4 | export const routing = defineRouting({
    |                                      ^
  5 |   locales: ["en", "es"],
  6 |   defaultLocale: "en",
  7 |   pathnames: {


Steps to Reproduce:

Set up a Next.js project with TypeScript and install next-intl.

Create an i18n/routing.ts file with the following content:
import { defineRouting } from "next-intl/routing";

export const routing = defineRouting({
  locales: ["en", "es"],
  defaultLocale: "en",
  pathnames: {
    // Custom route configurations
  },
});


Run npm run build to build the project for production.


This is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [{ "name": "next" }],
    "types": ["@testing-library/jest-dom", "jest", "node"],
    "paths": { "@/*": ["./*"] },
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "global.d.ts",
    "jest.config.js"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Environment:

next-intl version: 3.21.1
next version: 14.2.15
react version: 18.2
typescript version: 4.8.3
Operating System: macOS

Expected Behavior:
The project should build successfully without any TypeScript errors, just as it does during development with npm run dev.
Actual Behavior:
The build process fails with the TypeScript error mentioned above, indicating that defineRouting expects 0 arguments but received 1.
What I've Tried:

Changing the import statement to: import { defineRouting } from "next-intl";
Updating dependencies to the latest versions.
Deleting the .next and node_modules directories and reinstalling packages.
Adjusting TypeScript configurations in tsconfig.json.

Is there a recent change in the next-intl library affecting the defineRouting function? Should it now be called without arguments? How can I resolve this TypeScript error during the build process?
The fact that npm run dev works without issues suggests that the problem arises during the production build's stricter type checking.

This solves the problem using "typescript": "^5.6.3" or downgrade the @types/next-intl
next-intl routing.ts giving TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1
